# Symmetric difference of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{3,4,5,6\}$, and let $X = A\,\triangle\,B$, the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$. Then

A. $X = \emptyset$

B. $X = \{1,2\}$

C. $X = \{3,4\}$

D. $X = \{1,2,5,6\}$

I want to confirm if the answer is D, is it correct? 
Thanks

Comment: I am afraid there is some confusion in the notations ... The symmetric differen**ce** of the sets $A$ and $B$ is generally denoted by $A\Delta B$. The notation $A\cup B$ refers to the union of $A$ and $B$. That said, we have here $A\Delta B=\{1,2,5,6\}$ as stated in answer d).

Comment: Ok, if you meant symmetric difference, your answer is correct.

Comment: sorry for confusing you guys. I tried to put the notation of symmetric difference in the question, but find no way to do it.

Comment: If you meant $A\delta B=\{1,2,5,6\}$, then answer $D$ is correct.

Comment: To obtain $\Delta$ in mathjax (or latex) type Delta enclosed in a pair of $

Comment: [$\LaTeX$ and Mathjax typing guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  In this case `$X=(A\cup B)\triangle B$` produces $X=(A\cup B)\triangle B$.  Most people use $\Delta$, $\triangle$ or $\ominus$ for symmetric difference.

Comment: @quasi If I understood the original wording of the question correctly, it should have been $(A\cup B)\triangle B$, not simply $A\triangle B$.  These are not equal in this case.

Comment: Well, I assumed the simpler version, but perhaps I misunderstood. @Adren: Did you mean union followed by symmetric difference or just symmetric difference? If you meant the former, my edit needs to be corrected to reflect that.

Comment: Well, if it were *just* the symmetric difference, I see no reason for the U to have appeared in the original phrasing "*X = ( A U B) , then symmetric different to B*"

Comment: Well, presumably, Adren will clarify what was intended. In any case, you've answered both versions.

Comment: Thats for @pkim, the original poster, to clarify, not Adren.

Comment: Oops -- I missed that.

Comment: @pkim: There's confusion about whether you intended (1) union of $A$ and $B$ followed by the symmetric difference with $B$; or (2) just the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid any confusion with edits, there are two common interpretations to what you were asking.

With $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{3,4,5,6\}$

*The symmetric difference of $B$ with the union of $A$ and $B$*

- $(A\cup B)\triangle B = (\{1,2,3,4\}\cup \{3,4,5,6\})\triangle \{3,4,5,6\} = \{1,2,\color{red}{3},\color{red}{4},\color{red}{5},\color{red}{6}\}\triangle \{\color{red}{3},\color{red}{4},\color{red}{5},\color{red}{6}\} = \{1,2\}$

If this is what was intended to be asked, then no $d$ is incorrect.  The correct answer then would be $b$.

*The symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$*

- $A\triangle B = \{1,2,\color{red}{3},\color{red}{4}\}\triangle\{\color{red}{3},\color{red}{4},5,6\} = \{1,2,5,6\}$

If this is the intended question, then yes $d$ is correct.

Remember that to find the symmetric difference of two sets, you take the elements that are in exactly one of the sets.

(*in general the symmetric difference of $n$ sets results in those elements that are in exactly an odd number of the sets*)

Answer (score 0):

D is indeed correct, as $A \cup B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $A \cap B = \{3,4\}$ 
and their difference is set D. It's also the set of elements that occur exactly once among the elements of $A$ and $B$